# Under Mavericks with KeyRemap4MacBook my wireless keyboard doesn't register modifier keys

Tags: keyboard, macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have the hyper key setup working on my rMBP 13" terrifically, but why I connect to my Apple wireless keyboard (Bluetooth) none of the hyper key combinations work (it doesn't send the modifier). I have caps lock set to be disabled in System Preferences, and if I try it on my MBP right beside me the commands work, but they don't on my external keyboard. Why is this?

For the record it seems to be sending escape instantly, and not waiting for the key up event.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have "do not remap external keyboard"  checked in Keyremap4macbook preferences.

Answer (score 1):

In `System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys` dialog, select your external keyboard from the dropdown and make sure "No Action" is selected against the Caps Lock key.